# How to skip to the next iteration in case of an error

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

In Netlogo Behavior space, if one of the runs is throwing an error, how to skip that run and ask netlogo to proceed with the next run?

Is it even possible?

Comment: Be careful of your words: In your title you use step, but I think that's a common terminology to mean an iteration (tick) of the program. I don't think that's what you mean to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs,

> If you do want spreadsheet output, note that if anything interrupts
>   the experiment, such as a runtime error, running out of memory, or a
>   crash or power outage, no spreadsheet results will be written. For
>   long experiments, you may want to also enable table format as a
>   precaution so that if something happens and you get no spreadsheet
>   output you'll at least get partial table output.)

So, I'll assume this isn't possible and the best way to fix this would be to handle the situation where your code has an error. Alternatively, you could use the `carefully` command to handle the error messages.